# Why is there a limit in 9.9 when auto-converting from varchar to int?

Tags: sql-server

I tried the following in SQL Server:

```
SELECT '10.1' as Col
UNION
SELECT 5.1
```

^This doesn't work, but:

```
SELECT '5.1' as Col
UNION
SELECT 10.1
```

^ This works.

I tried with different numbers in the first value, and apparently all values less than 9.9 work. All values bigger than 9.9 don't work.

Comment: Usually this error getting for decimal or numeric data types wherein the precision of the column or variable is not enough to hold the value being assigned to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is all to do with data type precedence and implicit conversion. You have 2 different data types in your queries, a `varchar`, and a `decimal`, however, their length, precision and scale properties all differ.

In the first query you have a `varchar(4)`, and a `decimal(2,1)`. `decimal` has a higher data type precedence than `varchar`, so the latter is converted, implicitly, to the former. `10.1`, however, is too large for a `decimal(2,1)`, so an error occurs. Effectively what's happening is `CONVERT(decimal(2,1),'10.1')`, which fails too. The largest number a `decimal(2,1)` can store is `9.9`.

For the latter query, this works as `10.1` is a `decimal(3,1)`. `'5.1'` can easily fit in a `decimal(3,1)` so the implicit conversion works.

---

The real thing you should be doing, however, is ensuring that all datasets in your `UNION (ALL)` return the same data types. Then you don't have to deal with implicit conversions, and the errors that they might result in:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(decimal(3,1),'10.1') as Col
UNION ALL
SELECT 5.1;
```

Answer (score 1):

When data of different types must go into a single place, data type precedence rules decide which of the two types will be used.

In your first example, the system must choose between `char(4)` and `numeric(2,1)`. It chooses `numeric(2,1)` and `10.1` isn't going to fit in there. What it *doesn't* do is decide an appropriate type to convert the string to (say, `numeric(3,1)`) and then merge those types.

In your second example, `5.1` will fit in a `numeric(3,1)`.

Of course, it's not true to say that there's a limit of 9.9 converting varchar to int because a) we're converting to numeric, not int, and b) if you increase the size of the number in your first example:

```
SELECT '10.1' as Col
UNION
SELECT 50.1
```

Then no error occurs